# Pandas: groupby value_count filter by frequency and subcategory

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this in Pandas:

```
Session Rating
A       Positive
A       Positive
A       Positive
A       Negative
B       Negative
B       Negative
C       Positive
```

Using `counts = df.groupby('Session')['Rating'].value_counts()` I get a Series object like this:

```
Session Rating
A       Positive  3
        Negative  1
B       Negative  2
C       Positive  1
```

What I want to do is filter on two criteria:
1) filter by frequency, so where the count > 1
2) filter by Rating == 'Positive'

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50117068/pandas-groupby-value-count-filter-by-frequency) to for 1), but I'm unsure how to do 2), since it's a Series and i can't get the Ratings field. The expected result would be `A Positive 3`

Finally, I want to mask my original dataframe to exclude all those rows meeting those two conditions. Help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you post the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this combination, first filter the dataframe where Ratings == 'positive', then groupby and value_counts to get a series, lastly, use .loc with a lambda function to create a boolean for selection only the parts of the series greater than 1.

```
df[df.Rating == 'Positive'].groupby('Session')['Rating'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x>1]
```

Output:

```
Session  Rating  
A        Positive    3
Name: Rating, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I used your approach and modified it to get what I wanted:

    idxs = df[df.Rating=='Positive']['Session'].value_counts().gt(1)
    df = df.loc[~df['Session'].isin(idxs[idxs].index)]

Did not need groupby, turns out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `groupby.size`, followed by [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
res = df.groupby(['Session', 'Rating']).size().reset_index(name='Count')\
        .query('(Rating == "Positive") & (Count > 1)')

print(res)

  Session    Rating  Count
1       A  Positive      3
```